# Render :partial with :layout don't work in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

so i have a problem with `:partial` rendering...

I have:

`index.html.erb` view with content of `<%= render :partial => 'partial_test', :layout => 'partial_test' %>`
`index.html.erb' layout with content of`<%= yield %>`

`_partial_test.html.erb` view with content of simple string
`_partial_test.html.erb` layout with content of `<div id="_partial"><%= yield %></div>`

After rendering i get proper content from controller (view + layout) index action, but from rendering partial i get only content from view, layout is missing.

I should get something like this:
`<div id="index">
    <div id="_partial">
        simple string
    </div>
</div>`

but i'm getting
`<div id="index">
   simple string
</div>`

It's strange because when i render partial with layout from inside controller index action i get proper rendering of view + layout (only for partial).

Help needed :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of using

`<%= render :partial => 'partial_test', :layout => 'partial_test' %>`

what i needed to use was

`<%= render :partial => 'partial_test', :layout => 'layouts/partial_test' %>`

Comment: A couple significant things to note: a) This helper differs from the normal `render` helper in that when using a layout, `render` takes a hash with a `partial` key as opposed to taking a string as its first argument. b) The layout filename must be preceded with an underscore, e.g. an argument of `layouts/partial_test` would map to a filename of `layouts/_partial_test.html.erb`.

Comment: Also, here's a link to the relevant part of the docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#partial-layouts

Comment: Another difference from the normal `render` usage I just discovered: when passing locals when using a layout, a `locals` key is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

As I read the Rails docs, you don't want:

```
<%= render :partial => 'partial_test', :layout => 'partial_test' %>
```

You want:

```
<%= render 'partial_test', :layout => 'partial_test' %>
```

I'm not sure how/why your layout and partial have the same name, but please look at the Rails Guide at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html, Section 3.4.3.

Comment: Hi @Steve, i had read this guide, if i don't use `:partial` layout for partial won't load. File names are not irrelevant in this case. Thx for response.

Comment: In my experience this answer is not correct. The `partial` key _is_ necessary.